# D3.Js heatmap chart not showing hover texts / tooltips

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I have taken the heatmap chart from http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084 and modified it. I was excpecting to get tooltips using

```
cards.select("svg:title").text(function(d) {
    return "Tariff " + d.value;
});
```

The complete project is here: https://jsfiddle.net/8wtoqg6r/1/.

[image]

How can I get a hover event to show the tariff number (which is `d.value`) in a tooltip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip according to the example http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579. The relevant code looks like that

```
let tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([0, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "Tarif " + d.value;
  });

  svg.call(tip);

let heatmapChart = function(data) {
  let cards = svg.selectAll(".hour")
    .data(data, function(d) {
      return d.day + ':' + d.hour;
    });

  cards.append("title");

  cards.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return (d.hour - 1) * gridSize;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return (d.day - 1) * gridSize;
    })
    .attr("rx", 4)
    .attr("ry", 4)
    .attr("class", "hour bordered")
    .attr("width", gridSize)
    .attr("height", gridSize)
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return colors[d.value - 1];
    });

  cards.exit().remove();
};

heatmapChart(data);
```

A complete solution can be found in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8wtoqg6r/3/